# NGXS Actions are dispatched again when path is updated

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have a problem with NGXS Actions. All actions are dispatched(or handled) again when path is updated via Angular router.

I noticed that this happens when a path is changed
eg. `/news/today` -> `/news/labels/1`.
This do not happen when only param's value is changed.

I will appreciate any advice regarding what can I check, or how can I debug this

App workflow:

1. when button is clicked then url path is updated

```
 this.router.navigate([uri], extras);
```

2. there is a central component which dispatch NGXS Action when path is updated

```
combineLatest([cfg$, url$, urlParams$, queryParams$])
  .pipe(
     filter((vals) => vals.every(isNotNull)),
     map(([cfg, url, urlParams, queryParams]) =>
     this.createRequest(cfg!, url, urlParams, queryParams)
  )
)
  .subscribe((request) => this.store.dispatch(new GetNewsPosts(request)));
```

3. Data is loaded via Http Get

```
  @Action(GetNewsPosts)
  getNewsPosts(ctx: StateContext<NewsItemsModel>, { request }: GetNewsPosts) {
    console.log('GetNewsPosts', request);
    ctx.setState({ loadingFirstPage: true, pages: [], request });

    const response$ = this.service.getPosts(0, request); 
    return handleGetFirstPageResponse(ctx, dataName, response$); // returns Observable
  }
```

Versions:

- Angular 15.1.5
- @ngxs/store: 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with my code, the event was triggered, which dispatch a new value of cfg$, every time a path was updated

adding `debounceTime` helped me to find this out

```
combineLatest([cfg$, url$, urlParams$, queryParams$])
      .pipe(
        filter((vals) => vals.every(isNotNull)),
        debounceTime(30),
        map(([cfg, url, urlParams, queryParams]) =>
          this.createRequest(cfg!, url, urlParams, queryParams)
        )
      )
      .subscribe((request) => this.store.dispatch(new GetNewsPosts(request)));
```